# Android gradle test only one flavor

Tags: android, gradle

I've currently set my TeamCity instance to run `connectedCheck` on all my Android-projects. This is fine, all tests run and everything is good. Except, connectedCheck runs all tests for all product flavors. I currently have a lot of flavors, so this is wasted work for my projects as I do not really have any different code in the flavors. Any idea how I can make `connectedCheck` only run for one flavor?

Comment: Have you found a workaround to this?  I'm also interested in finding [some kind of separation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046259/is-there-a-way-to-only-run-a-specific-set-of-tests-in-an-android-gradle-project).

Comment: No, I couldn't spend any more time investigating this issue. My current setup just runs 'connectedCheck'. I just checked the gradle build tasks. See my answer below.

Comment: I got an answer on [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23065258/974369); it wasn't too painful but I use the separation of `@SmallTest` and `@MediumTest`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`./gradlew connected[Flavor]DebugAndroidTest`

Comment: What if i i have flaourA flavourB and flavourC and i just wanna test FlavourA and B?

Comment: @jonney, it should be ./gradlew connectedFlavorADebugAndroidTest connectedFlavorBDebugAndroidTest

Answer (score 12):

`./gradlew connectedBuildVariantAndroidTest`

Example:

`./gradlew connectedDevelopmentDebugAndroidTest`

Comment: This worked for me, but the accepted answer didn't. Seems strange.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Verified by checking `./gradlew tasks`

Answer (score 4):

As [vida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782870/vida) said you can run `./gradlew tasks` to check all possibilities to run gradle commands.

I'd like to suggest the following:
`./gradlew tasks | grep connected`.
This filter all connectedAndroidTest variants that can be runned.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a new task since I checked this the last time, "connectedAndroidTestProductFalvor_buildvariant".

I haven't had time to check this task yet, but the description reads "Installs and runs the tests for build ProductFlavor_buildvariant on connected devices."

Will post a result when I've been able to test this.

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to generate the apk for the android test :

```
./gradlew assemble[flavour]DebugAndroidTest
```