# Is there a way to only run a specific set of instrumentation tests in an Android Gradle project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci

I have an Android/Gradle project.  Whenever I want to run tests, I run:

```
./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest
```

which runs all my tests under the test folder of my project.

My test folder has several automation tests as well as non-automation tests.  I'm mostly interested in running the fast non-automation tests without the slow automation tests.

Is there a way to run just a specific set of tests, such as from one specific class or anything similar?  I'm basically asking about any kind of separation so that I can choose to run just a few tests when I want to.

---

Created a sample project [here](https://github.com/mendhak/android-gradle-test-sample/archive/master.zip).

Edit `local.properties` to point at your Android SDK.

Next, start up an emulator or connect a phone to your computer. Then you can run tests using `./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest --info`.  This runs all tests.

What I am unable to figure out is how to only run tests in, say, one class  and not all tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a specific instrumentation unit test with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565857/running-a-specific-instrumentation-unit-test-with-gradle)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Since Android Gradle Plugin 1.3.0**

Starting from version 1.3.0 you can (finally!) specify the arguments the Android Gradle Plugin have to pass to the `InstrumentationTestRunner`.

For example, if you want to run only the tests annotated with `@SmallTest` and ignore the others:

```
android {
  //....
  defaultConfig {
  //....
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    testInstrumentationRunnerArgument "size", "small"
  }
}
```

---

**Old workaround**
Prior to plugin 1.3.0 is not possible to do that but I've found a little workaound. Basically I've annotated with the `@SmallTest` annotation the fast tests and using a custom subclass of the `InstrumentationTestRunner` I'm able to run just them and not the whole suite.

You can found the example code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rciovati/8297685).

Comment: This helped me, I had to make sure my package name was `testPackageName "com.example.packagename.test"` and after that I was able to pass in `-PtestSize=small`.  Now my Travis builds don't randomly fail as I can ignore the Robotium tests.  Really appreciated.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  I didn't realize that `@SmallTest` is a standard JUnit annotation.  Here are the guidelines for `@SmallTest`, `@MediumTest` and `@LargeTest` (in my case I'm going to overload one of them to run a particular set of tests): https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/TPy1EeSaSg8

Comment: You can also use this feature to run everything **except** one annotation. `testInstrumentationRunnerArgument 'notAnnotation', 'android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest'`

Comment: @Riccardo what if I want to run both small and medium test?

Answer (score 2):

Also you can install test suit on the device and run it manually through adb. See [android docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsCommand)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please have a look [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#test_filtering). It should also work with an android project. Unfortunately as far as I know there's no way to rung single method - You can limit to whole suit only.

Comment: There is no test task in Android Gradle projects as it goes through their [plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).

Comment: OK. Thanks for clarification. Any sample project on GH to have a try? Beyond the fact that here's no `test` task I guess that there's still a possibility to configure a single test run. Will ask android devs for some details at work on tomorrow.

Comment: Cheers, modified the post to include a zip download.  I'd understand if many Android devs are still on non-gradle systems though as it's somewhat new.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at it!