# How can I run a specific set of Android instrumentation tests with Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, continuous-integration, android-gradle-plugin

I have multiple test packages:

```
com.mypackage.blackbox    - Robotium UI tests
com.mypackage.integration - REST integration tests
com.mypackage.unit        - low level unit tests
```

Our server team needs to be able to run just the integration tests on every push (they take a couple of minutes), but then run all tests every night (the black box UI tests take more than 10 minutes).

[This great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23065258/112705) provides a slightly hacky (but effective) way to do it by overloading an existing JUnit annotation like `@SmallTest` or `@LargeTest`.

[The Gradle documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#test_filtering) suggests that test filters are the way to do this, e.g.

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTestDevDebug --tests com.mypackage.integration.*
```

However, that fails with an `> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.` error (presumably because the Android Gradle plugin doesn't support everything that vanilla Gradle does?).

The same documentation says in future they plan to support these alternatives:

> - Filtering based on custom annotations (future)
> - Filtering based on test hierarchy; executing all tests that extend ceratain base class (future)
> - Filtering based on some custom runtime rule, e.g. particular value of a system property or some static state (future)

Does anybody know a clean way to get this to work right now?  For now I'm planning to use the `@MediumTest` annotation on the base class that all my integration tests extend, but I'd love to be able to specify particular package(s) instead.  Using `@MediumTest` or `@LargeTest` abuses those annotations, as both my integration and black box tests are large tests [according to the guidelines](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/TPy1EeSaSg8).

Comment: This doesn't really answer your specific question but I've been able to accomplish this by using Spoon (https://github.com/square/spoon).  Spoon wraps the Android unit test runner and provides some additional useful features (like building an HTML output page including screen shots). It also provides a technique for running specific test classes and methods.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046259/is-there-a-way-to-only-run-a-specific-set-of-tests-in-an-android-gradle-project)

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible with the addition of Android's recent [Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html), you can now use [`AndroidJUnitRunner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html) and filter the tests you run by your own custom annotations.

Filter test run to tests with a custom annotation (com.myapp.MyAnnotation in this example):

```
adb shell am \
  instrument -w -e annotation com.myapp.MyAnnotation \
  com.myapp/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

[Complete AndroidJUnitRunner Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html)

You'll need to annotate your test cases with your custom annotation to get this to work.  Example test case:

```
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import com.myapp.MyAnnotation;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class CalculatorTest {

    @MyAnnotation
    @Test
    public void testAddition() {
        //Do testing here
    }

}
```

Here is what your "MyAnnotation" would look like:

```
package com.myapp;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * My custom Annotation to specify a type of tests to run.
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To run specific tests using gradle you have to create custom instrumentation test runner class and run tests using that class. I.e. create class

```
package com.my.package;

public class MyInstrumentationTestRunner extends InstrumentationTestRunner {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle instrumentationArguments) {
        instrumentationArguments.putString("size", "medium"); // Run medium tests
        // Add more ...
        super.onCreate(instrumentationArguments);
    }
}
```

Then in your `build.gradle` set `testInstrumentationRunner` (it's under `android -> defaultConfig`, i.e.

```
// ...

android {
    // ...

    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.my.package.MyInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
}

// ...
```

Hope it helps!

Note. `build.gradle` is from `:lib`, the tests are located under `src/androidTest/java` where the `MyInstrumentationTestRunner` is created.

Answer (score 1):

[Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676843/112705) is the most versatile answer.  However, the simplest solution is probably to use the `-e package` option on the [InstrumentationTestRunner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html):

> **Running all tests in a java package:** adb shell am instrument -w -e
>   package com.android.foo.subpkg
>   com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

You can combine this option with using Square's [Spoon](https://github.com/square/spoon) library, as it allows you to specify either individual classes, or use  `-e` to pass options through to the test runner (e.g. the `package` option):

```
--class-name        Test class name to run (fully-qualified)

--method-name       Test method name to run (must also use --class-name)

--e                 Arguments to pass to the Instrumentation Runner. This can be used
                    multiple times for multiple entries. Usage: --e <NAME>=<VALUE>.
                    The supported arguments varies depending on which test runner 
                    you are using, e.g. see the API docs for AndroidJUnitRunner.
```

For the record, Shazam's [Fork](https://github.com/shazam/fork) has a more powerful regex option:

```
android.test.classes=REGEX - comma separated regexes that specify a pattern for the classes/packages to run
```