# Run specific tests without editing files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

You can currently run specific Android tests in Android studio by following the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046259/is-there-a-way-to-only-run-a-specific-set-of-tests-in-an-android-gradle-project)

```
android {
  //....
  defaultConfig {
  //....
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    testInstrumentationRunnerArgument "size", "small"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without editing Gradle files?

Comment: In Android Studio 2.1, right-click over the test class or the test package in the explorer tree to run just what's in there. In the source editor, each test method should have a "run" button in the gutter that can be used to run that individual test method. You can also set up run configurations for these scopes.

Comment: Is there any way to have similar GUI test selection for annotations such as `@SmallTest`?

Comment: I do not see an option for that, sorry.