# Exclude Gradle @LargeTest

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am trying to run unit test on a separate task from the UI tests that I have within the integration tests in Android Studio, unfortunately I have to use

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

in the build.gradle file so I cannot add the custom test tasks as far as I can tell. Since the UI tests are tagged as "@Test" and extend InstrumentationTestCase they get run whenever

```
gradle connectedCheck
```

is called which is not needed, instead I want one gradle command to run UI tests and one to run unit tests. I figured that I would be able to leverage tagging the UI tests as LargeTests but have not been able to complete a gradle task that can do this. I am not able to use the "test" task in the build.gradle since we are using the com.android.application plugin, and advice?

Thanks

Comment: I believe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046259/is-there-a-way-to-only-run-a-specific-set-of-tests-in-an-android-gradle-project

Comment: even usingtestInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"    testInstrumentationRunnerArgument 'notAnnotation', 'android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest' when calling gradle cAT it attempts to run the classes tag with @LargeTest and fail with the exception "No runnable methods" and I can never call the large tests either

Answer (score 3):

What ended up working for me is adding the

```
@LargeTest
```

using

```
import android.support.test.filters.LargeTest;
```

annotation to the tests I needed and then adding the following lines to the build.gradle

```
if(!project.hasProperty('android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.annotation')) {
        testInstrumentationRunnerArgument 'notAnnotation', 'android.support.test.filters.LargeTest'
    }
```

this way unless I specify in the command line to run the large tests they will,be ignored. To run the large tests use:

```
gradle cAT -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.annotation=android.support.test.filters.LargeTest
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this from command-line without modifying the build.gradle file:

```
./gradlew cAT -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.notAnnotation=android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest
```